# How to setup SVN in windows 7 which is in network and make it server for SVN?

Tags: svn

We need to use SVN for putting and sharing our projects between us team members in office. We are connected to the under the same network.

Can anyone please help me with some guidelines for SVN? How to set up the server side SVN in my PC and make other team members use it.

I have already tried setting up VISUAL SVN in my windows 7 but after everything, i couldn't really run it in browser. Its not authenticating me- i used the username and password of my pc.

And as far as i know, except me(as server side SVN will be in my pc) -other team members need to use Tortoise SVN for using my server SVN.

So, i didn't really succeed the way i tried. Please help me with guidelines- step by step process will be really helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you *need* to use SVN specifically? It sounds like you're just getting started, so do you have a choice of revision control systems? Normally SVN does *not* keep the repository on some team member's PC. It runs on a dedicated "always on" server that everyone connects to, often running an apache web server to allow access via http. If you really want to host from your PC a distributed choice like Mercurial or Git would probably be better.

Comment: Make sure that your machine is accessible via HTTP(S) on your LAN from other machines and install VisualSVN Server.